# Do Gaudiya Vaishnavas believe in eternal damnation?

Tags: gaudiya-vaishnavism, chaitanya, iskcon, achintya-bheda-abheda

Sri Madhvacharya who started the Brahma Sampradaya which have Dvaita Vedanta as its philosophy, believed in the concept of eternal damnation.This means that according to Madhvacharya, some demonic souls who have committed many sins are bound to be born in low births or even suffer in hell for an eternal time.
This almost feels like the abrahamic concept of eternal hell for non-believers. Abrahamic faiths are also known to be Dvaitic.

Gaudiya Sampradaya also came into being from Brahma Sampradaya and Gaudiya themselves consider Brahma as their first Guru in paramparam. Though the only difference is Gaudiyas believe in Achintya BhedaBheda while Madhavites believe in Dvaita.

So my question is is the concept of eternal damnation of Madhvacharya supported by Gaudiya Vaishnavas/ISKCON?

Comment: Simple answer: No. Although such a state of being in hell for a very long time is possible.

Comment: BG 16:`19  check it supports eternal damnation dont ever deride madhvacharya philosophy and compare it with abhrahamic faith without proper understanding.. RishX

Comment: Gaudiyas, Nimbarkis, Ramanujits dont subscribe to eternal damnation in their siddhanta, and speaking about Abrahamics they believe in eternal damnation of the soul.

Answer (score 2):

No. Gaudiya Vaishnavas concept of Jiva is Little Different from Madhva Sampradaya. We don't have the concept of 3 Different Jiva Categories. In Gaudiya Vaishnava Philosophy all the Jivas are Amshas of Sri Hari's Tatastha/Kshetragya Shakti and so they are Qualitatively same but Quantitatively different ie. the jiva is anu aatma or infinitesimal whereas Sri Hari is vibhu aatma or infinite, among them whoever will do Hari Bhakti will get Goloka, etc. There is no concept of Eternal Hell.   Some highly Wrongdoers may get Hell for a very very long time but would again get the opportunity to do Hari Bhakti.  There is no concept of Eternal Damnation.

Sometimes Acharyas give Concepts like Nitya Samsara, Nitya Naraka, etc according to time, place, and Circumstances. Gaudiya Vaishnavas respect those Philosophies however they don't take it literally.

Comment: Please provide some 'authoritative references' to your answer. Kindly visit [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/guidelines-for-new-users-answering-questions).